# How to get Angular 1.x Scope Using Selenium's python library

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

The code I have so far setting up Selenium is in this  git gist. How would I assign the scope to the commented out variable named scope?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chromedriver = "/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("Webpage") # I don't want to reveal the page (internal work stuff)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "property")))

'''
scope = ?
'''


#links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.property div.info a")]
#print(links)

driver.close()
```

Comment: What you want to achieve in the end ? Its not angular but plain js and html , once parsed by angularjs

Comment: I want to return a specific object on the scope in json form